# Using Vue 3 provide/inject for all props

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am just curious to hear your thoughts, can't find many articles regarding this topic, mainly copy/paste from the official docs.

Currently, I am in a process of creating a component that can have many props, more than 50 I guess. This component will have a few child components, at most up to 3-4 level depth.

Somewhere in the middle of the process, I realized that I am passing and declaring a new prop in at least 3 places. This results in ugly code, just a list of passed props in every file.

Now to the question. Is there any downside of just providing all props to the `provide` API and accessing what I need? The code I have looks like this:

**File that exports injectionKey I can access in other components**

```js
export const injectionKey = Symbol();
```

**Main component**

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { provide, toRefs } from 'vue';
import { injectionKey } from './key'

const props = defineProps({ ...manyPropDefintions });

provide(injectionKey, toRefs(props));

</script>
```

**In children components**

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { inject } from 'vue';
import { injectionKey } from '../key'

const injectedProps = inject(injectionKey);
</script>
```

Tested it and it looks and behaves fine, can access them all and they are reactive. Regarding the first question, is this considered a bad or good practice, can there be any performance issues and such, or I should not worry and proceed with this approach? To add, when all definitions are cleared, the code is much cleaner.

Comment: Your question suggests to me that it may be time to fully refactor your code from the ground up.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is the point, I am doing some cleaning up, however I can't do much about amount of props

Comment: For deeply passed props, you can use $attrs. One problem is that you pass writable refs that can be accidentally written, while props are readonly. Another problem is a big load of props itself. This indicates a big problem with component design. And no, passing all refs to all children is certainly not a good practice, you lose track of where props are used, and how, this makes untangling the clot of props considerably more complicated.